# How to determine version of the actually installed maven-gpg-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

As documented on [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/usage.html), here is the `maven-gpg-plugin` block as used in the POM for all three of my projects:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can you tell the version of this plugin that is actually installed on my computer? Is the fact that 1.5 seems to work good enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there could be multiple installed you are interested to know which one is being used effectively you need

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

this will render effective `pom.xml` and you can figure out which version is effective

Comment: Really good to know: [Maven's help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html). The `maven-gpg-plugin` tag generated by `help:effective-pom` is exactly as in my question-post--version 1.5 and all. Thank you @JigarJoshi.